# How to parse nested JSON?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have nested JSON that I retrieve from a webpage where I need to parse some information , the JSON format is:

```
{"total":52,"arrivalAirportCategories":null,"fares":[{"outbound":{"departureAirport":{"countryName":"Italia","iataCode":"NAP","name":"Napoli","seoName":"napoli","city":{"name":"Napoli","code":"NAPLES","countryCode":"it"}},"arrivalAirport":{"countryName":"Austria","iataCode":"VIE","name":"Vienna","seoName":"vienna","city":{"name":"Vienna","code":"VIENNA","countryCode":"at"}},"departureDate":"2020-11-10T20:25:00","arrivalDate":"2020-11-10T22:00:00","price":{"value":7.99,"valueMainUnit":"7","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"flightKey":"FR~9476~ ~~NAP~11/10/2020 20:25~VIE~11/10/2020 22:00~~","flightNumber":"FR9476","sellKey":"0~N~ ~FR~NALA3~ALA3~~0~2~~X","previousPrice":{"value":7.99,"valueMainUnit":"7","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"priceUpdated":1601300034127},"inbound":{"departureAirport":{"countryName":"Austria","iataCode":"VIE","name":"Vienna","seoName":"vienna","city":{"name":"Vienna","code":"VIENNA","countryCode":"at"}},"arrivalAirport":{"countryName":"Italia","iataCode":"NAP","name":"Napoli","seoName":"napoli","city":{"name":"Napoli","code":"NAPLES","countryCode":"it"}},"departureDate":"2020-11-19T18:10:00","arrivalDate":"2020-11-19T19:45:00","price":{"value":7.99,"valueMainUnit":"7","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"flightKey":"FR~9475~ ~~VIE~11/19/2020 18:10~NAP~11/19/2020 19:45~~","flightNumber":"FR9475","sellKey":"0~N~ ~FR~NALA3~ALA3~~0~2~~X","previousPrice":{"value":7.99,"valueMainUnit":"7","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"priceUpdated":1601300015069},"summary":{"price":{"value":15.98,"valueMainUnit":"15","valueFractionalUnit":"98","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"previousPrice":{"value":15.98,"valueMainUnit":"15","valueFractionalUnit":"98","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"newRoute":false,"tripDurationDays":9}},{"outbound":{"departureAirport":{"countryName":"Italia","iataCode":"NAP","name":"Napoli","seoName":"napoli","city":{"name":"Napoli","code":"NAPLES","countryCode":"it"}},"arrivalAirport":{"countryName":"Spagna","iataCode":"BCN","name":"Barcellona El Prat","seoName":"barcelona-el-prat","city":{"name":"Barcellona","code":"BARCELONA","countryCode":"es"}},"departureDate":"2020-10-29T08:55:00","arrivalDate":"2020-10-29T10:55:00","price":{"value":9.99,"valueMainUnit":"9","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"flightKey":"FR~5711~ ~~NAP~10/29/2020 08:55~BCN~10/29/2020 10:55~~","flightNumber":"FR5711","sellKey":"0~N~ ~FR~NZOCTDRP~ACZS~~0~4~~X","previousPrice":{"value":28.99,"valueMainUnit":"28","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"priceUpdated":1601398928349},"inbound":{"departureAirport":{"countryName":"Spagna","iataCode":"BCN","name":"Barcellona El Prat","seoName":"barcelona-el-prat","city":{"name":"Barcellona","code":"BARCELONA","countryCode":"es"}},"arrivalAirport":{"countryName":"Italia","iataCode":"NAP","name":"Napoli","seoName":"napoli","city":{"name":"Napoli","code":"NAPLES","countryCode":"it"}},"departureDate":"2020-10-31T12:35:00","arrivalDate":"2020-10-31T14:35:00","price":{"value":9.99,"valueMainUnit":"9","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"flightKey":"FR~5710~ ~~BCN~10/31/2020 12:35~NAP~10/31/2020 14:35~~","flightNumber":"FR5710","sellKey":"0~N~ ~FR~NZOCTDRP~ACZS~~0~3~~X","previousPrice":{"value":9.99,"valueMainUnit":"9","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"priceUpdated":1601384481431},"summary":{"price":{"value":19.98,"valueMainUnit":"19","valueFractionalUnit":"98","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"previousPrice":{"value":38.98,"valueMainUnit":"38","valueFractionalUnit":"98","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"newRoute":false,"tripDurationDays":2}},{"outbound":{"departureAirport":{"countryName":"Italia","iataCode":"NAP","name":"Napoli","seoName":"napoli","city":{"name":"Napoli","code":"NAPLES","countryCode":"it"}},"arrivalAirport":{"countryName":"Italia","iataCode":"GOA","name
```

And the information I need are: `arrivalAirport ( CountryName)   , departureDate and arrivalDate and from the summary the summary":{"price":`

I have tried something like:

```
for valori in output['fares']:
    print(valori["outbound"])
    for notizie in valori["outbound"]:
        print(notizie['sellKey'])
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: `but it doesn't work` how so? Please put the error in your post (not a comment).

Comment: your json is not valid - maybe you didn't include it all in your message, but if its not valid, nothing will work.

Comment: It's a dictionary not an array. You can loop through a dictionary with `for key, value in valori["outbound"].items():`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: It's a JSON object, not a dictionary. See [JSON spec](https://www.json.org).